# Referencing "private methods" in a closure

Tags: javascript

```
var Foo = (function () {

    var foo = function() { };

    var privateMethod = function(){ };

    foo.prototype = {
        init: function() { 
            console.log(this.privateMethod); //undefined
        }
    };

    return foo;

})();
```

I know that I can access `privateMethod` directly without using the `this` pointer. But since I come from the c# world, I would like to use it for readability purposes.

Is there any way to reference my "private methods" using a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can only use `this` to refer to "public" methods. If you really want to use a `something.method` notation, you could use:

```
var Foo = (function () {

    var foo = function() { };

    var private = {
       privateMethod : function(){ };
    }

    foo.prototype = {
        init: function() { 
            console.log(private.privateMethod); 
        }
    };

    return foo;

})();
```

Comment: Ok, would it make any sense to add all the foo-methods using `prototype` rather than creating "private" methods, even though I'm only using them inside the "class"?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense in prototypal inheritance. Just keep in mind that properties and methods inside the prototype are shared by all instances (meaning, no instance has its own copy of them). If you want to set some property value on a specific instance, you'll be actually creating a local property that will shadow the one on the prototype -- and yes, that may seem confusing...)

Comment: But in this case I know that I'm only going to create one instance. Sorry, should have mentioned that. Would it still be a good idea to move my methods to .prototype?

Comment: If it's a singleton, you gain nothing from using a prototype. Just declare everything as `this.property` or `this.method`. Actually, you could even use an object literal to create the singleton.

Answer (score 2):

`privateMethod` is not specific to each instance of `foo`. Just reference it without the `this.` qualifier—although you probably want to log the results of a function call, not the function itself:

```
console.log(privateMethod());
```

Comment: The OP already knows that. The question is if it's possible to reference "private" methods (closed over variables) using `this`.

Comment: @bfavaretto - The OP already knows what? OP certainly didn't know to simply eliminate `this.`.

Comment: "I know that I can access privateMethod directly without using the this pointer. But since I come from the c# world, I would like to use it for readability purposes."